# How to get the data from dynamically table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a dynamically table I need to get the date from it any place in the script.....

the table

```
$('#update_panel').html('Loading Date....');

$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/GetCountries',
    type: 'GET',
    datatype: 'Json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            var $data = $('<table></table>').addClass('table table-responsive table-striped');
            var header = "<thead><tr><th>Country ID</th><th>Country</th></tr></thead>";
            $data.append(header);

            $.each(data, function (i, row) {
                var $row = $('<tr/>');
                $row.append($('<td/>').html(row.CountryId));
                $row.append($('<td/>').html(row.CountryName));
                $row.append($('<td/>').html("<a href='/home/Save/" + row.CountryId + "' class='popup'>Edit</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href='/home/Delete/" + row.CountryId + "' class='popup'>Delete</a>"));
                $data.append($row);
            });

            $('#update_panel').html($data);
        }
```

I tried it but it didn't work

```
    $("#mytable tr").click(function () {

        var countryId = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text().trim();
        alert(countryId);
    });
```

How to reach the table in the Dom?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some observations and a possible solution:

- Your dynamic table is missing the ID (mytable)
- Once it is added your code should work fine. See the code below,

```js
var data = [];
var row1 = {};
row1.CountryId = "100";
row1.CountryName = "USA";
data.push(row1);

var row2 = {};
row2.CountryId = "101";
row2.CountryName = "Germany";
data.push(row2);


if (data.length > 0) {
            var $data = $('<table id="mytable"></table>').addClass('table table-responsive table-striped');
            var header = "<thead><tr><th>Country ID</th><th>Country</th></tr></thead>";
            $data.append(header);


            $.each(data, function (i, row) {
                var $row = $('<tr/>');
                $row.append($('<td/>').html(row.CountryId));
                $row.append($('<td/>').html(row.CountryName));
                $row.append($('<td/>').html("<a href='/home/Save/" + row.CountryId + "' class='popup'>Edit</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href='/home/Delete/" + row.CountryId + "' class='popup'>Delete</a>"));
                $data.append($row);
            });

            $('#update_panel').html($data);
  }

$("#mytable tr").click(function () {

        var countryId = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text().trim();
        alert(countryId);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="update_panel"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Vimalan it's working but how can i use $("#mytable tr").click(function () {

        var countryId = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text().trim();
        alert(countryId);
  });

in different place outside the table function... something like 

function GenerateTable()
{ var $data = $('<table id="mytable"></table>')  }

and in a different place i want use
$("#mytable tr").click(function () {

        var countryId = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text().trim();
        alert(countryId);
  });

Comment: put the event handler in a function and call it after the GenerateTable()

Answer (score 1):

```
   $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/GetCountries',
                type: 'GET',
                datatype: 'Json',
                success: function (data)
                {
                    if (data.length > 0)
                    {
                        // HERE I HAVE APPLIED 'id' ATTRIBUTE TO TABLE
                        var $data = $('<table id="mytable"></table>').addClass('table table-responsive table-striped');
                        var header = "<thead><tr><th>Country ID</th><th>Country</th></tr></thead>";
                        $data.append(header);
                        $.each(data, function (i, row)
                        {
                            var $row = $('<tr/>');
                            $row.append($('<td/>').html(row.CountryId));
                            $row.append($('<td/>').html(row.CountryName));
                            $row.append($('<td/>').html("<a href='/home/Save/" + row.CountryId + "' class='popup'>Edit</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href='/home/Delete/" + row.CountryId + "' class='popup'>Delete</a>"));
                            $data.append($row);
                        });
                        $('#update_panel').html($data);
                    }
                }
            });
            //USE 'on' EVENT WHEN YOU WANT TO TRIGGER EVENT ON DYNAMIC DOM
            $("#update_panel").on("click", "#mytable tr", function ()
            {
                // IT WILL SELECT ALL 'td' CHILDREN OF CLICKED 'tr' ELEMENT.
                // THEN WE USED .first() SO IT WILL SELECT ONLY FIRST 'td' ELEMENT
                var countryId = $.trim($(this).children("td").first().text());
                alert(countryId);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your table did't have an id `#mytable`. Change `$("#mytable tr").click(function () {` into :

```
$('#update_panel').on('click','.table tr',function () {...});
```

Or simply adding id `#mytable` into table

```
 $('<table id="myTable"></table>')
```

And register it handler using `.on` like so :

```
$('#update_panel').on('click','#mytable tr',function () {...});
```